# Implementing Spring ChainedTransactionManager according to the "best efforts 1PC" pattern

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions, jms

The best effort 1PC is nicely described in [this post](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2009/jw-01-spring-transactions.html?page=6). The author, David Syer, who works for SpringSource, provided an implementation of a `ChainedTransactionManager` extending the Spring `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` class.

This particular transaction manager can start *n* transactions, e.g., JDBC or JMS sessions, and perform commit/rollback using *n* instances of `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager`, one per resource. This is very useful where XA drivers are not available. Since the post is very old, the code works fine with Spring 2.5, but it fails with Spring 3+.

There is a [request ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3844) to implement a similar feature in Spring 3+. I'm willing to give it a try but I thought I'd ask first: are there any implementations out there?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can try using the ChainedTransactionManager from spring-data-neo4j, but what kind of database nowadays does not provide an xa driver? If you need another idea, this blog http://infinispan.blogspot.com.ar/2011/06/faster-infinispan-based-second-level.html show how a cache system hooks to JTA synchronization, to avoid XA, in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks I am using that now, someone suggested it on Spring's Jira. And for example Vectorwise doesn't provide an XA driver. Giovanni

Comment: Hi Giovanni, we are also trying to do a similar setup for our spring batch application using best effort 1PC pattern. Can you please let  us know your experience in using this approach. If you can provide us a sample configuration file for reference it would be greatly helpful. my email id is ravikiran763@gmail.com . Thank you in advance

Comment: @rave763 I am no longer working on this project and don't have access to the code anymore but I had good luck with `ChainedTransactionManager` back then. My config was mostly custom, i.e., not your standard Spring config. I never liked the XML config approach anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Luciano, I found a perfectly working implementation of `ChainedTransactionManager` in:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-tx</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

class name: `org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager`

**EDIT**:

The `ChainedTransactionManager` is now part of Spring Data Commons as of [version 1.6.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/changelog.txt).

Comment: Hey do you guys know if many instances of ChainedTransactionManager (now moved to Spring Data Commons) can be used from different threads to handle transactions across different resources? Or does it HAVE TO be a singleton?

Comment: @Giovnni Botta Guess who's old code I'm working on? :)

Comment: @JohnHumphreys-w00te good luck with that!