# Spring @Transactional on one service method spanning over two Hibernate transaction managers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I was wondering if it is possible to use two transaction manager in one service methods. 
Because due to the limitation of client's mysql db configuration, we have got 2 different datasources within one database, i.e., one user/pwd/url per schema. Thats why i have to configured two transaction managers. Now I got problem when it comes to the service implementation. See the following code:

```
public class DemoService{
    ...
    @Transactional(value = "t1")
    public doOne(){
        doTwo();
    }

    @Transactional(value = "t2")
    public doTwo(){

    }
    ...
}
```

if I using this code pattern, i always got the exception

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

If i run the two methods seperately, it workd fine. 
Did i miss something? Or there is other work around here?
Any advice would be appreciated.

btw: some of my configuration

```
    <bean id="sessionFactorySso" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:sso.vo/*.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="generateDdl">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${dialect} </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceSso"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceSso" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${driver}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${sso.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${sso.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${sso.password}"/>
         <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="2" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="automaticTestTable" value="test_c3p0" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
    <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="true" />
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="1000" />
    <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerSso" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactorySso"/>
    <qualifier value="sso" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerSso" />
```

Comment: The `@Transactional` on `doTwo` is ignored when called from `doOne`. Due to the fact that Spring used proxies for aop, only external method calls are intercepted.

Comment: @M. Deinum so you mean there is no better solution for this?

Comment: You would have to inject the bean into itself and call the method on that (just as you would do with an EJB).

Comment: thanks man i may try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to enlist two data sources in one transaction you need XA(Global) Transaction.

Therefore you need to:

1. Set the Spring JTA transaction manager
2. You Hibernate properties should use the JTA platform settings
3. Your data source connections should be XA complaint
4. You need an application server JTA transaction manager or a stand-alone tarnsaction manager (Bitronix, Atomikos, JOTM)
5. You will need two session factory configurations, one for each individual data source.
6. And you won't have two transaction managers: t1 and t2, but instead you will enlist two transactional XA data sources that will be automatically enlisted in the same global transaction, meaning you will have two XA connections being enlisted in the same global transaction. The XA transaction will use the 2PC protocol to commit both resources upon commit time.

Checkout this [Bitronix Hibernate example](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Hibernate).

Comment: I found this post http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-jta-multiple-resource-transactions-in-tomcat-with-atomikos-example tried it out and it works!!! Thanks a lot. Just one question, if I use Bitronix or Atomikos, should i worry about the typical mysql connectivity problem which c3p0 solved? Put it another way should  I also embed c3p0 or they have their own solution?

Comment: Bitronix has it's own XA complaint pool. There is a very close relationship between their pool and the transaction management semantics so you should not embed other connection pool. c3pO works fine, but for resource local transactions. If you ever want to give a try to the fastest non-XA CP, the check HikariCP.

Comment: so in a word, Bitronix will handel the connection problem like c3p0 does?

Comment: I can only assume that you refer to "connection pooling" whenever you say "the c3pO connectivity problem"? Bitronix will provide you a stand-alone JTA transaction manager along with its own connection pooling support. If you want extra metrics and monitoring you should also check [FlexyPool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Inject the bean into itself and use the reference to call doTwo().  This really goes against the whole idea of IoC and AOP so I don't recommend it.
2. Switch to compile time weaving.  Rather than using proxies, Spring (actually the AspectJ compiler) will add the bytecode to start/stop transactions to your class at compile time.  There are pros and cons to this approach. See [this page](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) for more details.
3. Use load time weaving.  Same as #2 except that your classes are modified as they are loaded rather than at compile time.  IMO, Java classloading is complicated enough.  I'm sure this works great for some folks but I personally would avoid this.
4. As Vlad pointed out, you can use JTA and XA.
5. Start a new transaction against transaction manager 2 within doOne() before calling doTwo().  RTFM on [programmatic transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic).
6. Check out [ChainedTransactionManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817909/implementing-spring-chainedtransactionmanager-according-to-the-best-efforts-1pc).  It essentially aggregates multiple transaction managers and does a "best effort" with commit/rollback.  This is NOT a true two-phase commit like Vlad's solution.

All of these except for Vlad's solution (#4) have the potential to leave the databases in an inconsistent state.  You need to use JTA/XA/two-phase commit to ensure consistency in the event that one of the TX managers throws an exception at commit time.

Comment: I didn't know about ChainedTransactionManager, but if you have at most one non-XA data source you can benefit from the [Last resource Commit optimization](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/LastResourceCommit) supported by the Bitronix TM.